# Parse JSON on Windows Phone

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net, windows-phone-8

I have a web service which generates some JSON for me which I want to parse on Windows Phone. I'm new on this Topic, so I don't know how to do this, because in the JSON there are lists with different numbers of entries, so I can't get the item with the index, because I don't know it. How can I get dynamical data into my Windows Phone app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your Json message this page can generate classes:
http://json2csharp.com/

Use this page to get the reference-code to deserialize/serialize Json in C#:
http://json.codeplex.com/

Then for example to deserialize your Json response:

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
}
```